# Dynamic view object within dynamic form in HA mode

Tags: oracle-adf

The issue is not reproducible in HA mode

We are hitting an application issue with dynamic view object within dynamic form in HA mode. As indicated below we have a dynamic form in UI which binds to dynamic view object:

```
<dynamic:form value="#{bindings.ZcqDqInput1Iterator}" id="idf" />
```

The ZcqDqInput1Iterator binds a dynamic view object within an AM  :

```
<iterator Binds="ZcqDqInput1" RangeSize="25"    DataControl="DQRealTimeUtilityAMDataControl"    id="ZcqDqInput1Iterator"/>
```

The application has been enabled with HA mode recently, to  handle passivation and activation scenario. I have overriden the activateState within AM to recreate the view object. that binds to view object ZcqDqInput1.

Navigating to this screen from some steps shows the below error:

```
Caused by: oracle.jbo.InvalidParamException: JBO-25006: Value 00010000000EACED00057708FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF passed as parameter String to method Constructor:Key is invalid: {3}.
at oracle.jbo.Key.parseBytes(Key.java:543)
at oracle.jbo.Key.<init>(Key.java:185)
at oracle.jbo.server.IteratorStateHolder.getCurrentRowKey(IteratorStateHolder.java:35)
at oracle.jbo.server.ViewRowSetIteratorImpl.activateIteratorState(ViewRowSetIteratorImpl.java:3998)
at oracle.jbo.server.ViewRowSetIteratorImpl.getRangeSize(ViewRowSetIteratorImpl.java:646)
at oracle.jbo.server.ViewRowSetImpl.getRangeSize(ViewRowSetImpl.java:3194)
at oracle.jbo.server.ViewObjectImpl.getRangeSize(ViewObjectImpl.java:12199)
at oracle.adf.model.binding.DCIteratorBinding.initSourceRSI(DCIteratorBinding.java:2114)
at oracle.adf.model.binding.DCIteratorBinding.callInitSourceRSI(DCIteratorBinding.java:1854)
```